# Sort through pandas dataframe with columns of different lengths to find matches

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 4 columns, but different numbers of rows and several blank (e.g., isnull / NaN) cells.

For example, here's a baby dataframe with the situation:

```
data = {'mrn1':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4],
        'race1':['', '', '', 'white', 'white', 'black', 'black', 'black', ''],
        'mrn2':[1,1,3,3,4,6],
        'race2':['black', 'black','black','black', 'white', 'white']}
dfx = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
dfx = dfx.transpose()
```

which produces:

| mrn1 | race1 | mrn2 | race2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1 | black |
| 1 |  | 1 | black |
| 1 |  | 3 | black |
| 2 | white | 3 | black |
| 2 | white | 4 | white |
| 3 | black | 6 | white |
| 3 | black |  |  |
| 3 | black |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |  |

What I am trying to accomplish is to fill in the missing `race1` column (not concerned about race2) by iterating through  both `mrn1` and `mrn2`, and where there is a match, assign `race2` in the blank (missing) `race1` cell. Alternatively (perhaps less messy), create and append a new `race3` column that indexes to `mrn1` and assigns `race2` if `race1 == null` and otherwise assigns `race1`.

desired final product:

| mrn1 | race1 | mrn2 | race2 | race3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1 | black | black |
| 1 |  | 1 | black | black |
| 1 |  | 3 | black | black |
| 2 | white | 3 | black | white |
| 2 | white | 4 | white | white |
| 3 | black | 6 | white | black |
| 3 | black |  |  | black |
| 3 | black |  |  | black |
| 4 |  |  |  | white |

I have attempted several iterations of join, merge (all types), and df.iterrows to no avail. In all cases, I can only coordinate the matching and assignment if/when the mrn1 and mrn2 rows match. There are no variations of code that come close, so there is no use providing any examples of code I have tried. Any help will be most welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
dfx.loc[(dfx.mrn1==dfx.mrn2) & (dfx.race1==''), 'race1'] = dfx.loc[(dfx.mrn1==dfx.mrn2) & (dfx.race1==''), 'race2']
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a master DataFrame of the race values using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to stack races together. Then [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to remove missing rows and [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) (keeping those from race1 and removing those from race2) then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) back to the initial DataFrame:

```
key_df = (
    pd.concat([
        dfx[['mrn1', 'race1']]
            .mask(dfx['race1'].eq(''))  # Convert empty string to NaN
            .set_axis(['mrn1', 'race3'], axis=1),  # Rename to match output
        dfx[['mrn2', 'race2']]
            .set_axis(['mrn1', 'race3'], axis=1)  # Rename to match output
    ]).dropna()  # Drop NaN
        # Drop Duplicates (keeping values the first values from race1)
        .drop_duplicates(['mrn1', 'race3'], keep='first')
)

# Merge DataFrame to get new column
dfx = dfx.merge(key_df, on='mrn1')
```

`dfx`:

```
  mrn1  race1  mrn2  race2  race3
0    1            1  black  black
1    1            1  black  black
2    1            3  black  black
3    2  white     3  black  white
4    2  white     4  white  white
5    3  black     6  white  black
6    3  black  None   None  black
7    3  black  None   None  black
8    4         None   None  white
```

`key_df` for reference:

```
   mrn1  race3
0     2  white
1     3  black
2     1  black
4     4  white
5     6  white
```

---

A more compacted version without the comments and taking advantage of the various function defaults:

```
cols = ['mrn1', 'race3']
dfx = dfx.merge(
    pd.concat([
        dfx[['mrn1', 'race1']].mask(dfx['race1'].eq(''))
            .set_axis(cols, axis=1),
        dfx[['mrn2', 'race2']].set_axis(cols, axis=1)
    ]).dropna().drop_duplicates(cols)
)
```

Comment: That is it! A very elegant and quick solution. Thanks very much.

Comment: Now to execute across 400k rows!